# Unpacking bytes from a pattern

Tags: java, kotlin

How to unpack an array of bytes according to a pattern? eg. "uint:16,uint:12,uint:12"

In Python, there is [bitstring](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) module with *unpack* method, but I can't find any Java equivalent.

Comment: Please pick a language. The answers for Java or Kotlin are likely different.

Answer (score 2):

Am not certain which version of Java you are using...

here's the link to the java reference for the BitSet class : [BitSet.html](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html)

You can use the `valueOf()` function with a byte array to get a BitSet.  Then use the BitSet.get() funciton to extract out the bits for a specific range

so assuming you have a byte array...

```
byte[] bytes;

BitSet bigSet = BitSet(bytes);

BitSet uint16set = bigSet.get(0,16);
BitSet uint12set1 = bigSet.get(16, 16+12);
BitSet uint12.set2 = bigSet.get(28, 28+12);

long uint16Long = uint16set.toLongArray()[0];
long uint12Long1 = uint12set1.toLongArray()[0];
long uint12Long2 = uint12set2.toLongArray()[0];
```